# request error (invalid_request) spring rest api

Tags: rest, web-services, api, spring-boot, http-proxy

I wrote a Rest API using Spring boot and Rest Template .Simplest one . Here is the code that I wrote in the controller .

```
package wsJson;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestCon {

    private AtomicLong id;

    public Bean b;
    @RequestMapping("/bean")
    public Bean getBeans(@RequestParam(value="name")String name){
        return new Bean(id.incrementAndGet(), name);

    }

}
```

Bean is simple and the main class just runs the Spring Boot App .
Whenever I run the code it runs in localhost:8080 . But as I go to the URL
http://localhost:8080/api/bean?name=User1

it gives

> Request Error (invalid_request)
>
> Your request could not be processed. Request could not be handled This
>   could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed
>   request.

Can anyone help me understand the problem and how to solve it?
This code works normally, but in my office I am sitting **behind proxy network** and this code fails like this! Does anyone have any idea why is it so!

**Edit**:
After I run the app , I can see after entering the controller following gets logged in console:

> 2017-08-25 16:43:18.325  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for
>   @ControllerAdvice:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@d3d15a:
>   startup date [Fri Aug 25 16:43:16 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-08-25 16:43:18.419  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
>   "{[/greeting],methods=[GET]}" onto public hello.Greeting
>   hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String) 2017-08-25
>   16:43:18.422  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto
>   public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   2017-08-25 16:43:18.422  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
>   "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
>   2017-08-25 16:43:18.444  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path
>   [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2017-08-25 16:43:18.444  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto
>   handler of type [class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2017-08-25 16:43:18.495  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path
>   [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2017-08-25 16:43:18.633  INFO 1056 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX
>   exposure on startup 2017-08-25 16:43:18.817  INFO 1056 --- [
>   main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2017-08-25 16:43:18.833  INFO 1056 --- [
>   main] hello.Application                        : Started Application
>   in 3.063 seconds (JVM running for 3.729)

main class:

```
package wsJson;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);

    }

}
```

bean class:

```
package wsJson;


public class Bean {

    public long id;
    public String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Bean(long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

*App made using spring-boot 1.5.6-RELEASE*

Comment: try to launch it in debug mode and add a breakpoint inside the getBeans method

Comment: Try to specify the HTTP method, something like this `@RequestMapping(value = "/bean", method = RequestMethod.GET)` on your `getBeans` method

Comment: @SukmaWardana Tried adding Method already. Happens the same. By the way I am sitting behind a proxy server, which I forgot to mention . Localhost is skipped though .

Comment: @yamenK I tried debugging .It goes into the controller but not inside the method! And it takes me to some spring reference classes .So I lose the track of it and unable to point it!

Comment: you should use http://localhost:8080/api/bean?name=X because of name is required param

Comment: @Nikolay yes,tried that .Same thing happens .Url mentioned was wrong in the question ,  http://localhost:8080/api/bean?name=User1 this is the correct one i tried with . when that didn't work I tried setting a default value to that param as well. Nothing works :(

Comment: add Bean.java and stacktrace

Comment: @Nikolay how to do that? I am using STS on Eclipse Neon .

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your spring-boot application. 
If you have an exception in your application logs please let us know about the stack trace. In your code snippet id is not initialised so your code can't work: 
here is an example of code i tested :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestApplication {

    private AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/bean")
    public String getBeans(@RequestParam(value="name")String name){
        return new Bean(id.incrementAndGet(), name).toString();
    }

    class Bean{
        public Bean(long l, String name) {
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Test your application locally without that proxy so your can be sure your application works.

You posted your app startup logs and it looks like your controller is not mapper . Maybe your controller is not scanned by the application. 
You controller has to be in a sub package of the package containing the class that is annotated by `@SpringBootApplication` so the component scanner can see it.

Comment: I added some logs in my question . If it helps you,please check .

Comment: looks like your controller is not scanned by the component scanner.

Comment: But the application enters the controller! Can you point out why this happens?

Comment: how do you know the application enters the controller? when your controller is correctly scanned you should see : `Mapped "{[/api/bean]}" onto public ...` in the statup logs.

Comment: I tried printing something inside controller constructor and it gets printed but never enters the method I wrote inside controller .

Comment: this is weird... can you post the content of your main class? or better, if you have nothing sensitive can you give us the whole project code via a github repo ? What is the version of boot you are using ?

Comment: I added other 2 files in my question edit . When it wasn't running for a large API code that I wrote,I tried with this simple one even this wasn't working. Appreciate your help .

Comment: i copied your classes to a github repo : https://github.com/areguig/stackoverflow_45878462 . it works. can you tell me what in your code is different ?

Comment: Is that so! Nothing is different but I am sitting behind a proxy which I can't disable and check without my network administrator's permission .How does it affect my application?